# Create a function that fires only once after app is installed on phone

Tags: android, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps, visual-studio-cordova

I'm developing a mobile app using ApacheCordova/Phonegap.
I need a function that sends a SMS to me once per install. If I put my function on "DeviceReady" it will be run each time the app opens.
Is there any solution for a function to be run when app is installed OR when it runs for first time?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a field to the localstorage and on startup just check if that field exists. So something like this:

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem("installed") == undefined) {
   /* run function */
   window.localStorage.setItem("installed", true);
}
```

**Edit:** The reason I prefer this over the other methods is that this works on iOS, WP, etc as well, and not only on android

Comment: I use this method in my Cordova apps as well.

Comment: Thanks, Easy to use for a beginner.

Comment: god, cordova.. was it so hard to just create a hook for this?

Answer (score 8):

Check if it is the first time with a method and then perform the action if that method determines that it is the first time.

Ex:

**isFirstTime() Method**

```
private boolean isFirstTime()
    {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();
        // Send the SMS

        }
    return ranBefore;

    }
```

You may want to add it to your `onCreate()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    topLevelLayout = findViewById(R.id.top_layout);



   if (isFirstTime()) {
        topLevelLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: I'm developing my app using ApacheCordova, With JavaScript. it seems your code is written on JAVA or something else

Answer (score 0):

This should be what u are searching for:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) 
{
// run your one time code
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: You can just google for "SharedPreferences" too, that will give you what you want

Comment: I'm not that familar with ApacheCordova/Phonegap but actually you can just do that in ApacheCordova

Answer (score 0):

Use some boolean value if its true don't call that function other wise call that function example is here

```
if(smssent!=true)
{

//call sms sending method

}


else

{

//just leave blank or else notify user using some toast message

}
```

Note:-the boolean value store in some database like sharedprefernce or sqllite, files....